# Mac OS 10.15 TextEdit will not save edited documents "The document “1969 GREYHOUNDS email ref.txt” could not be saved"

Tags: textedit

The problem does not seem to occur on the machine hard drive (when saved to the desktop); only on mounted server drives.
A variant on the message is: "The document “1969 GREYHOUNDS email ref test copy.rtf” could not be autosaved."
The server is also running Mac OS 10.15  Catalina.

Comment: This could be a server permissions issue.  Did you check to see if you have the appropriate permissions for that share?

Comment: The Catalina computer trying to save from TextEdit to the server (another Catalina computer) has read & write access.

Comment: How did you verify?  Can you test it out by attempting to Crest a document in that share?  When you get that error, can you still read write to that share?

Comment: If I create a document in TextEdit (or Photoshop CC 2020) and save it to a share from a Catalina machine acting as a file server, then change the document, and then try to save it, it does not save. I can then save it with a different name or to a different location on that share, it saves correctly. If I change the document and save, (now under the new name) it fails. If I save as the old name, it successfully writes over the original document.